# Define the scope in which script tags execute

Tags: javascript, html, scope

So I understand that when script tags are executed it's in the global scope, I was wondering if there was any way to make them execute in a local scope. For example:

```
function scoped() {
    const scopedVariable = '10';
    const scr = document.createElement('script');
    scr.src = '//cdn.blabla.com' //third party script
    document.body.appendChild(scr);
}
```

What I want is for the code that's executed in the script to have access to the `scopedVariable`. Meaning, I want the script to be executed within the `scoped()` execution context.

Comment: No, there's not. You'd have to download the script using xhr or `fetch`, and then `eval` the contents to achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: I figured that was probably the way I would have to go.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options in modern environments:

1. Use a module. That's a `type="module"` [`script` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) on browsers. Modules have their own scope, like a function call does. (They also have the benefit of defaulting to strict mode, and being deferred by default so they don't execute until the HTML parsing is complete.) If you have to support browsers that don't support modules (such a IE11), you can use bundlers like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/).
2. Use a function call — e.g., a wrapper function, like this:

   ```js
   (() => {
       // Your code here
   })();
   ```

Other than #1 above, you can't change the scope that the code at the top level of a script loaded via a `script` tag runs in.

#2 works in older environments as well, if you use a traditional function instead of an arrow function.

Comment: Okay. Option two is out if I want to scope a 3rd party library (e.g. jquery). Could you elaborate more on the `type=module`, does the 3rd party script have be structured in a specific way to work as a script module? Secondly, when you say they have their own scope, is it possible for me to define the scope in which a 3rd party script runs using the module attribute?

Comment: @Jacob - You didn't mention 3rd party scripts in your question. Typically code has to be written with the intention that it will be used as a module, not least because otherwise it's usually written with the assumption that it's running at global scope, so may rely on the `this` value referring to the global object, top-level declarations being globals, etc. Also, since module code isn't run at global scope, for anything outside of that code to make use of what it provides, it has to do something to make those things available -- it needs to export them. Whether any particular 3rd ...

Comment: ... party script has those issues will depend entirely on the script's contents. If it's jQuery, specifically, that you want to scope, that's actually really easy: After loading it in the usual way, from within whatever scoping construct you want, do `var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);`. That makes jQuery release the only two globals it creates (`$` and `jQuery`). So even though it's loaded at global scope, you've undone the effects of that. But the details vary depending on the script.

Comment: You usually have the option, of course, of taking a copy of the script, modifying it sufficiently to make it behave properly as a module, and using that copy instead. You can't get it from a CDN (at least, not one you can't push content to), but...